# DataFrame column containing list within double quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` about movies and one of the columns is `genre`.

The entries of this column are in the form of list like -

```
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, 
 {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, 
 {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, 
 {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
```

My aim is to extract the genre from the list and store them as a list such as `['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Romance']`.

When I print the entries of the column for example - 
`data['genres'][1]` it returns the list within the quotes (datatype : string)

```
"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"
```

Can someone help to get the list without the quotes? like `[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]` I should be able to take it from there.

When I create my custom example, it works as expected and returns a `list` without quotes.  For example -

```
ref = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[1,2,3],[4,3,2]]})
ref['col'][0]
```

This returns a list (without quotes).

Comment: Okay, so it's not a list, but a string whose contents look like a list. Go figure...

Comment: It would be better if you could show the code that created the DataFrame in the first place, or maybe even the process that produced whatever raw file data you created the DataFrame from. Chances are the best way to solve your problem is earlier in the process.

Comment: You can replicate it. Just create a `csv` file with a column containing lists. After you import it as a df, you will see the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there are string representation of lists, so is necessary first convert it to list of dicts and then extract by `get`:

```
a = [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, 
     {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, 
     {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'},
     {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':a}).astype(str)

import ast

df['genres'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).get('name'))
print (df)
                                col   genres
0      {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}   Comedy
1       {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}    Drama
2   {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}   Family
3  {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}  Romance
```

If is necessary get all values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcd'),'col':a}).astype(str)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df.pop('col')], index=df.index))
print (df)
   a     id     name
0  a     35   Comedy
1  b     18    Drama
2  c  10751   Family
3  d  10749  Romance
```

Comment: Perfect! What if I want to get a list without quotes (just this)?

Comment: Or if need only lists `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))`